# How does JWT Encryption work?

Tags: encryption, authentication, jwt

What is the message flow, or sequence that enables JWT encryption of the payload?

(opposed to OAuth / OpenIDConnect which doesn't encrypt the payload)

Answer (score 2):

I downvoted your question due to the fact I believe it to be answered by the canonical resources on JWT, https://jwt.io/introduction/.

Happy to reverse that if I missed some aspect of your question, but I do think you just need to check that link - it seems to cover both your initial question and the follow up in comments

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: [RFC 7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516)

Longer answer:

- it's sign then encrypt scheme
- encryption is two-step:

  - encrypt the payload with random symmetric key
  - encrypt the key with RSA

Since it's public key crypto on the latter phase, you need some scheme of PKI to handle public key availability.

Comment: Do you mind expanding on how the public keys are exchanged?

Comment: Anything you will, it's not the part of JWT scheme itself, hence the PKI remark.